# How do I render a partial and switch controllers while rendering in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionview

How do I switch controllers when rendering a partial? `render` doesn't seem to accept a `:controller` parameter. It is always using the initial controller that started the view. I can't put the method into the model because it makes use of the current user. It would probably work if I copied the method into all the controllers, but I think that is messy as it is specifically related to that one controller.

#### URL

```
http://localhost:3000/tags/cat
```

#### Route

```
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'tags#show'
```

#### View

```
=render @tag.posts
```

#### Partial

```
- if userVotes(post) > 0
```

#### Controller That I Want

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :userVotes
```

#### Error

> Showing C:/Users/Chloe/workspace/SeenIt/app/views/posts/_vote.haml where line #7 raised:
>   undefined method `userVotes' for #<#:0x27eb200>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just put the helper method in the application controller.

Comment: I was hoping to keep the related code together as it's only relevant to posts_controller.